# fortran code for comparing two sets of variables

Tags: fortran, row

I am trying to take a row of data where character locations 21:28 is the x value and character location 29:36 is the y value. I want to put those two sets of numbers in two variables and compare the two. Then if x <= y I don't want to write it to a new file else, I will write to the new file.

below is my code, but it is difficult to learn fortran so parts are missing.

```
program open
implicit none




call getarg(1,"block2.gro")
open(12,file="output.gro",status ='new')

Line =0
x = (21:28) !from input file to be x variable
y= (29:36)  !from input file to be y variable
row =       !unsure if I need a variable to contain the row
Line=line +1
    if (line .ne. 2) then
        if x < y
        write(12,*) row 
        line = line+1
        else 
        line=line +1
    end if

end program open
```

any help or useful places to learn fortran would be appreciated!

Comment: *it is difficult to learn fortran*  Pfff, try learning C++ :-)

Comment: I understand that the question is about Fortran. Writing reliable analysis code for simulation takes more than syntax, however. Have you considered to use a library dedicated to the reading of such files? Such as https://chemfiles.org/chemfiles.f03/latest/

Comment: I will look into chemfiles, perhaps this will make life easier!

Answer (score 2):

When you're learning a new language, you need to start slowly. I have the feeling that you're trying to do too many things at once.

Here are just some of the things that won't work:

1. You're using `implicit none` which is good, you should. But you're not declaring any variables. You use several variables (`line`, `x`, `y`, `row`) but never tell the compiler what type they are.
2. `getarg` is a subroutine that **returns** the contents of a command line argument. That means that you need to pass a `character(len=<something>)` variable as the second parameter, not a constant. This will fail.
3. You're never actually opening the input file, or read from it.
4. The `x = (21:28)` is not valid syntax, but I guess you know that.
5. I think there's supposed to be a loop in there somewhere, but there isn't.

By the way, you're not even telling us whether `x` and `y` are integers or floating point values.

Fortran is actually surprisingly flexible when reading numbers from a text file. If x and y are the only numbers in the text file, you can just do `read(<unit>, *) x, y`:

```
program read_block
    implicit none
    real :: x, y
    integer :: ios

    open(unit=101, file='block2.gro', action='read', status='old')
    do
        read(101, *, iostat=ios) x, y
        if (ios /= 0) exit
        print *, x, y
    end do
    close(101)
end program read_block
```

If there are other characters in there, you might have to use an explicit format:

```
read(101, '(20X, 2F8.3)', iostat=ios) x, y
```

Or, if you want the whole row anyway, you can read the whole row, then extract the values of `x` and `y` out of it:

```
real :: x, y
character(len=100) :: row     ! make sure that the length is sufficient to hold entire line
integer :: ios

...

read(101, '(A)', iostat=ios) row
if (ios /= 0) exit
read(row(21:28), *) x
read(row(29:36), *) y
...
```

I would recommend that you try to run this code, see what it does, and use your google skills to go on and *understand* what every line does and why it does it.